# Dictionary Iteration Won't run fully

Tags: python, dictionary, enumerate, forex, currency-exchange-rates

so, i am trying to write code that allows you to 1) input a phrase 2)input a string with the currencies you want to convert from and to (e.g. USD EUR; EUR GBP) 3) exchange rate of those two.

if you put in "I had USD 300 and then I had USD 400," (1), "USD EUR" (2), and 4 (3), it should return "I had USD 300 (~EUR 900) and then I had USD 400 (~EUR 1600).

However, my code below only "converts" the first reference to USD (USD 300, but not USD 400), returning - "I had USD 300 (~EUR 900) and then I had USD 400". I am not sure what I am doing wrong. if you see an error in my code, please let me know! thanks in advance :)

```
phrase = "I had USD 300 and then I had USD 400"
currency = "USD EUR"
ratio = 4

if phrase and currency:
    z = phrase.split()
    for order,word in enumerate(z):
        dictionary = {order : word}
        for i in dictionary.values():
            if i == currency.split()[0]:
                firstplace = z.index(i)
                if currency.split()[1] not in z[int(firstplace) + 2]:
                    convertednumber = (int(float((z[int(firstplace) + 1])))) * int(float(ratio))
                    z.insert(int(firstplace) + 2, f'(~{currency.split()[1]} {convertednumber})')
                    emptyphrase = " "
                    phrase = emptyphrase.join(z)
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass

print(phrase)
```

P.s. I know this is not a particularly efficient way of doing this, but I am just trying to test things out :)

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: And you do know that `else:` / `pass` is useless and can be deleted, yes?

Comment: A big part of the problem is that you are modifying `z` while you are iterating through it.  That doesn't work.  The other big problem is that `firstplace = z.index(i)` is always going to find the FIRST occurrence of USD.  Really, you need to be handling words one by one, and copying each word into a NEW list.

Comment: @Prune Thank you very much for that and my apologies. I edited the post.

Comment: Your edited code does not run.  You replaced the `input` statements with illegal code, and ignored the remainder of the posting guidelines.  Please finish the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but there are problems.  The punctuation at the end of "400." gets used as part of the number.  That's OK here, but it makes for an awkward sentence.  But it can give you the basic idea.

```
phrase = "I had USD 300 and then I had USD 400."
currency = "USD EUR"
ratio = 4

new = []
handle = False
for word in phrase.split():
    new.append( word )
    if word == currency.split()[0]:
        handle = True
    elif handle:
        convertednumber = int(float((word))) * int(float(ratio))
        new.append( f'(~{currency.split()[1]} {convertednumber})')
        handle = False

print(' '.join(new))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful and does the job! i am a little unsure about how the program inserts the ~EUR 1200 after USD 300 and not after just USD (i expected the latter after reading your code, but it works)

Comment: I think I got it - your code finds USD in the sentence, runs the iteration one more time (we have USD 300 added to the list at this point) and then adds the converted number. Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  Just set a little "state" rememberer.  And by the way, version 1 of my code did exactly what you said.  "USD (~EUR 1200) 400".